# Access Cassandra Node on the Azure Cloud from outside

Tags: azure, cassandra, connection, virtual-machine, datastax

I have created a Linux VM with a single node Cassandra cluster installed.
    Cassandra.yaml has the following:
    seeds: 
    listen address: 
    rpc address: 
    netstat -an check with all required port are up and listening.  (i.e. 9160,     9042)
    I am trying to connect my application which is outside of the Azure cloud to     access the cassandra cluster in the cloud.  Looks like the connection between     the outside host to the Azure cloud Cassandra node has been block.
Wonder if there is a true restriction to access Azure VM from out of network.  Is there a way to access this cassandra node from outside?
If someone can answer my question would be very nice.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to the "Endpoints" of your virtual machine:
[image]
At the bottom click on "Add", and add new endpoints for these ports. 
[image]
[image]
Then you will need to manage ACL for each endpoint, defining the IP ranges of the allowed and blocked IP addresses. 
[image]

Keep in mind that, if the internal IP that is used by the virtual machine, is different from external (public) IP, that is used by the client, then depending on a driver you may need to teach it how to do address translation. Otherwise, the cluster will report only internal IPs upon the discovery request, which will obviously be not accessible from outside.

From this and from the security prospective I would recommend setting up cassandra cluster inside of the virtual network, and accessing it via VPN.

There is a comprehensive tutorial how to do it here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-nodejs-running-cassandra/